# AnimateSharedLayout was assembled in version 5 of motion framer, how to redo the code to make it work?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

i have some code:

```
export const NavBar = () => {

const [activeIndex, setActive] = useState(0)

return (
    <>
        <div style={{
            display: "flex",
            borderRadius: '15px',
            margin: '0 0.5rem',
            width: '100%',
            fontSize: '2.1vh',
            alignItems: "center",
            fontWeight: 600,
            position: 'relative',
            justifyContent: 'space-around'
        }}>
            <AnimateSharedLayout>
            {
                menuData.map((item, index) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={item}
                        item={item}
                        isSelected={activeIndex === index}
                        handleClick={() => setActive(index)}
                    />
                ))
            }
            </AnimateSharedLayout>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}

const MenuItem = (props) => {
const {
item,
isSelected,
handleClick,
} = props;

```
return (
    <motion.div
        onClick={handleClick}
        style={{
            color: '#2c2b2b',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        }}
        animate={{color: isSelected ? '#502bd8' : '#2c2b2b'}}
    >
        {isSelected && <ActiveLine/>}
        {item}
    </motion.div>
);
```

}

const ActiveLine = () => {
return (
<>
<motion.div
layoutId='a'
style={{
width: '100%',
height: '0.5vh',
position: 'absolute',
top: '41px',
backgroundColor: '#502bd8'
}}
></motion.div>
</>
);
}

How to make it work?